# Pandas Querying and Count function column selector syntax

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having difficulty understanding why [[]] are needed to select certain columns after running a query and count for a dataframe.
For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(125)
N = 4_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size=N),'sad_mad':np.random.randint(10, size=N),'test':np.random.randint(2, size=N,)})
df.A.replace([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],inplace=True)
# print(df.head(n=20))
# print(df.tail(n=20))

sum = 0
for i in range(10):
    result = df.query("sad_mad == @i").groupby(by=['A']).count()[['sad_mad']]
    print(f"Result for {i} is \n{result}")
    sum+=result['sad_mad'].sum()
    print(f"sum: {sum}")
    print("=====================================")
    print(type(result))
print(df.columns)
print(result.columns)
```

The above works, but the following does not, I get a key error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(125)
N = 4_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size=N),'sad_mad':np.random.randint(10, size=N),'test':np.random.randint(2, size=N,)})
df.A.replace([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],inplace=True)
# print(df.head(n=20))
# print(df.tail(n=20))

sum = 0
for i in range(10):
    result = df.query("sad_mad == @i").groupby(by=['A']).count()['sad_mad']
    print(f"Result for {i} is \n{result}")
    sum+=result['sad_mad'].sum()
    print(f"sum: {sum}")
    print("=====================================")
    print(type(result))
print(df.columns)
print(result.columns)
```

I expected [] to be used in order to select the column I wanted, and [[]] to be used when I wanted to select multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Double brackets gives you a dataframe (because you could be looking up more than one column - in which case a dataframe is the right container), while single brackets gives you a series (on which it makes no sense to lookup the `sad_man` column, just apply the sum on the only axis).

See:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(125)
N = 4_000_000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size=N),'sad_mad':np.random.randint(10, size=N),'test':np.random.randint(2, size=N,)})
df.A.replace([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J'],inplace=True)
# print(df.head(n=20))
# print(df.tail(n=20))
i = 0
grouped_count = df.query("sad_mad == @i").groupby(by=['A']).count()
type( grouped_count[['sad_mad']]), type(grouped_count['sad_mad'])
# prints (pandas.core.frame.DataFrame, pandas.core.series.Series)
```